# itextsharp - PDF files are stapled when they are printed out

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I am using itextsharp to merge and print pdf files from a printer with stapling feature. When the files are printed out, the documents are stapled together. The printer is HP LaserJet M9050 MFP PCL6. I wonder if I can turn off the stapling feature grammatically?

Comment: It's probably easier to remove the staple cartridge :)

Comment: A quick search of the PDF spec finds no instance of the word "staple" so I don't think there's anything that iText can help you with. Whatever is doing the printing should have a profile that you can change the defaults on.

Comment: i would think it should be off in the printer by default and only applications that support it send the command.

Comment: PDF is a page layout language.  With the exception of printer's marks, trapping, and separation layers, there are no provisions for device control.